# How to configure domain / dns to use an application in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns

I currently have a client who owns a domain and hosting service with a working website in Hostgator. Ex: mydomain.com

And i also have an application on my AWS EC2. What we would like to do is redirect your domain to this application, so that when i access your domain: mydomain.com my application opens.

> Could someone give me a light on how I could do this? What settings should I do so much on her current hosting (hostgator) as much on my part on AWS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just go to your hosting provider hostgator --> Goto Modify DNS Records --> Create an A record where u give value as IP address of your EC2 instance. wait for 1-2 hours.